# Find $\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{e}|\ln x| dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to calculate this integral?

$$\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{e}|\ln x| dx$$

It is an obvious integral if the function is under the integral without modulus. The whole catch is in the module.

Comment: Where is ln(x) positive and negative?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ajhisuekar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use that

$$
\int_{1/e}^{e}\left|\ln\left(x\right)\right|\text{d}x=\int_{1/e}^{1}\left|\ln\left(x\right)\right|\text{d}x+\int_{1}^{e}\left|\ln\left(x\right)\right|\text{d}x
$$
Can you now discuss the value of $\left|\ln\left(x\right)\right|$ in each interval ?

Comment: I think the upper limit of the second integral should be $e$, not $1/e$, right?

Comment: @an4s You are fully right